# How can install sensu-plugins through a proxy or by offline package

Tags: sensu

I am using Debian 7 amd64, sensu (version 0.28.4-1).

I install sensu-plugins through a proxy with the command:

`/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/gem install sensu-plugins-redis  --user-install --no-document -p http://myproxy:3128 --verbose -s https://rubygems.org/`

But have an error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - send(2)
```

When I try to directly install it in a server, which have directly internet connection, everything is successful.
I don't know why.

I also find key work: install sensu-plugins by offline package, but not have recommendation.

Please help me, thanks so much.

Comment: I looks like you don't have enough privileges to run the command. Try to run it as root.

Comment: Dear Kobbe, I runed it as root. But aslo have that error